# Mysql: how to update a table column based on another table with a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql

### Using mysql 7.0

Lets say I have two tables `products`, `orders`

### orders

```
id | date | latest_product_name

1 | ... | NULL
```

---

### products

```
id| order_id | name | created_at 

1 | 1        | Ball | 2020-07-10

2 | 1       | Car  | 2020-07-11
```

How can I generate a query that updates `order`'s `latest_product_name` column with `Car` in our case for order 1, because it was created at the latest date.

of course this would update every order with it's latest product

something like:

```
UPDATE orders SET latest_product_name = Latest.name
FROM (
 SELECT p.name, DISTINCT(p.order_id) as order_id
 FROM products as p
 Order BY latest_file_date DESC
) as Latest
WHERE Latest.order_id = orders.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below way -

```
with cte as 
(
SELECT name,order_id, row_number() over(partition by order_id order by created_at DESC) as rn
FROM products 
)

UPDATE orders join cte
    on cte.order_id = orders.id
    SET latest_product_name = cte.name where rn=1
```

Comment: this query doesnt pass validation

Comment: I've updated the query - you can check now @WalksAway

Answer (score 0):

This query specifically retrieves the product that was added last

```
UPDATE orders SET latest_product_name = 
 (select prod_name  
 FROM products prods
where prods.order_id = orders.id
 and prods.created_at = (select max(created_at) 
                            from products prods_
                            where prods_.order_id = prods.order_id));
```

The following will achieve the same result, and is more compact, but perhaps not as logical

```
UPDATE orders SET latest_product_name = 
 (select prod_name  
 FROM products 
 order by created_at desc
 limit 1
);
```

[Se how both solutions work at this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2b4855/1)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I have updated my answer now.